# NSPredicate for to-many relationship, where a relationship (NSSet) must contain Entities defined in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Given the following Core Data Model:

```
-> : to-one releationship  
->>: to-many relationship

Entity A ->> Entity B 
Entity B -> A // each B belongs to exactly one A  
Entity B ->> B // a B can be related to other B's
```

So in class `A`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *Bs;
```

In class `B`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) A *A;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *Bs;
```

Assume I have an `NSArray *myArray` containing `(Bj, Bk)`.

**What I want is to fetch all `B`'s which belong to `Ax` and are related to `Bj` and `Bk`**:

The code below works, but is completely ugly, since I have to hardcode the NSPredicate based on the number (here it's 2, but it could be 10 or so) of `B`'s in the array:

```
NSEntityDescription *fetchedEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"B" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"A == %@ and (Bs contains %@) and (Bs contains %@)", Ax, [myArray objectAtIndex:0], [myArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

**How can I rewrite the predicate so that it is more generic?** It must be so obvious, but I just don't see it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"A==%@ AND (ALL %@ IN Bs)", Ax, myArray];
```

do what you expect? I am not sure (and away from my OS X box) whether this predicate is translatable to SQL for the Core Data SQLite engine. You may need a [SUBQUERY](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html) expression:

```
[NSPredicate preidcateWithFormat:@"A==%@ and SUBQUERY(Bs, $x, $x IN %@).@count == %d", Ax, myArray, myArray.count];
```

This assumes that the items in `myArray` are unique.

Comment: Thx for the quick response. Your first solution raises an Exception: unsupported predicate (null). The second works (had to fix @count and the missing ). But it's very slow. My hardcoded solution takes around 0.012 seconds, whereas the subquery solution takes around 10 seconds...

Comment: Unfortunately what you're asking for (a general solution) is indirect conflict with an efficient SQL query against a relational engine. I think you have to pick one or the other. What was the syntax error exactly? I will correct the post.

Comment: huh. did you correct the query already? or did i mix your solution with the ones from the SUBQUERY docs? My bad: Your solution works perfectly, sorry, and it rocks, average time is 0.000016 seconds! I think i mixed your solution with one from the docs: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"A == %@ and (SUBQUERY(Bs, $x, $x IN %@).@count == Bs.@count)", Ax, myArray, myArray.count]; This one is really bad, taking around 10 seconds average. Because of the Bs.@count! Thank you very much, saved my day!