# Predicate for finding an entity where a to-many relationship matches a given set of entities

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I have an entity `Thread` that has a to-many relationship `participants` to an entity called `Contact`.

How can I fetch the `Thread` entity which has the exact same `Contact` entities at its destination as a `NSSet` of `Contacts` I've collected elsewhere.

Something like this:

```
NSSet *participants = [NSSet setWithObjects:<Contact>, <Contact>, <Contact>];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Thread", self.managedObjectContext];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.participants == %@", participants];

fetchRequest.entity = entity;
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
```

Comment: You're supposed to say 'I tried this and got this problem.' What about the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807532/nspredicate-for-to-many-relationship-where-a-relationship-nsset-must-contain ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just compare sets in a predicate like this `self.participants == %@", participants`. This predicate might work better:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"ALL participants IN %@ && participants.count == %@", 
    participants, @(participants.count)];
```